# Why libraries from maven repo not compile?

Tags: java, maven, repository

I have an interesting task to compile some libraries from project repo.

1. I get jar with library sources using mvn dependency:sources.
2. I unpacked java files to src/main/java folder.
3. I run 'maven clean install'

Some libraries compiles ok, but some don't - some packages not found, because they not in sources jar and not in library pom.xml. Why the authors of libraries do this?

For example try to compile this lib: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/edu/ucar/netcdf/4.2/

Error: package ucar.unidata.util does not exist. And where and how i must get this package? And why authors not include this to jar or pom file?

The problem is massive, not only this library affected.

Comment: 1. To help you, please publish the full error as you see it in the Maven output 2. It is rather unusual to try to compile sources yourself and they are not meant to be used for that. What is the reason you want to do this?

Comment: Because the author is a student, most likely.

Comment: I have a task - build libraries from sources. Error: [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/projects/testrepo/edu/ucar/netcdf/4.2-min/src/main/java/ucar/nc2/units/TimeUnit.java:[36,25] package ucar.unida
ta.util does not exist

Comment: So what is the reason behind your task? Why should you build the library from source instead of use the existing jar? Usually, to build something from source, you search for their GitHub/GitLab/whatever page and get the project from there to build it.

Comment: Sorry, if this seems rude. But I often encounter questions that are XY problems, and it is much easier to help the OP when I understand which _original_ problem should be solved by the concrete question.

Comment: The task is to compile poject ONLY from sources: first build libraries, then build project on builded  libs.

Comment: You said that already, but WHY? I understand that this task was given to you by someone (boss? supervisor?), but could you give me more background information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do not understand the concrete error you gave, let me state that it is in general *not possible* to rebuild a jar if you just have the sources jar and the POM.

Lots of things may be missing, like resources, tests and the project structure itself (if it was a multi-module project), and some POMs are "flattened", so that important plugin calls etc. are removed.

So you need to get used to the fact that this may or may not work.

Usually, people just use the jar as it is. If for some reasons (that you are not revealing, although I asked you twice) you need to compile from source, I can (in this order):

1. Look for a github/gitlab page of the project (often given in the POM, or you find it in google) and draw the project from there.
2. Fiddle with the sources and POM until you can compile the project (as you would with any broken project). This may or may not succeed.
3. Don't use the library but write the necessary stuff you need yourself.